# Why are systems of linear equations of the form $A x = 0$ called homogeneous?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Why are systems of linear equations of the form $A x = 0$ called *homogeneous*?

What is the motivation behind the word "homogeneous"?

Answer (score 2):

Because in the equation
$$
\begin{align}
A_{11}x_1 + \cdots + A_{1n}x_n &= 0 \\
&\;\, \vdots \\
A_{11}x_1 + \cdots + A_{1n}x_n &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
all terms are of degree $1$. On the other hand, the equation $Ax=b$ also has terms of degree $0$.

Comment: Still, differential equations such as $y'' + y = 0$ are also sometimes called homogeneous, vs $y'' + y = \cos x$ which is inhomogeneous. I think it refers to the fact that the set of solutions forms a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Homo means 'same' and genus means 'type'

> Equations of the same type

All exponents of collected terms are the same type - degree 1

Comment: But isn't a system of the form Ax = b called inhomogeneous?  This is still a system of linear equations, but it is inhomogeneous. It seems there's more to the definition than its degree.

Answer (score 1):

‘Homogeneous’ also refers to the property that if $x$ is a solution, any multiple $\lambda x$ is also a solution. This means the left-hand side of the equation is a *homogeneous function* (of degree $1$ in the present case).

Answer (score 0):

A system of equation is **linear** if any equation is first degree and is **homogeneous** if any term (not null) in any equation has the same degree.

So homogeneity refers to the fact that all therms have the same degree.